# How to display images on DLP using HDMI for 3D printing?

Tags: dlp, python

I am working on a DLP based 3D printer. I already sliced my STL file to multiple layers. Each layer is saved as a SVG file. Because its an SVG file, I can always convert each layer to PNG/JPG file if desired.

I have a TI DLP Lightcrafter 4500 module connected to my laptop using the HDMI. The DLP shows up as a second monitor on my laptop. I am using LabVIEW to control all components of the printer.

Question 1: How I can programmatically display my desired image file on the DLP projector. I would prefer to use Python or LabVIEW to display my desired image onto the entire screen of the DLP. Is there any way to achieve this on Windows? I also have the option of using Raspberry Pi + LabVIEW using LINX (http://www.labviewmakerhub.com/). I looked at nanoDLP (http://www.nanodlp.com/), which is a control software for DLP based 3D printers. However, I can't figure out how they manage to display the desired images to the DLP.

Question 2: Is it possible to display a SVG file to the DLP instead of PNG/JPG/BMP? If not, how do I know which resolution to use when converting SVG to PNG/JPG/BMP?

Comment: I suppose it's not a solution but maybe it will help you anyway. You could use this app http://www.stefandidak.com/windows-layout-manager/ it allows you to say - this window will be open here. Experiment with names/processes and other "selectors". I use it with success.

Comment: I believe most people building DLP printers simply use Creation Workshop. It's free (older versions) and pretty powerful for this.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: [Printrun](https://github.com/kliment/Printrun/) is 3D printer host software written in Python with limited DLP support. You can checkout how it [display layers](https://github.com/kliment/Printrun/blob/master/printrun/projectlayer.py).
NanoDLP directly talk to GPU through Dispmanx which makes it Raspberry Pi only.

Q2: Printrun supports SVG. To convert SVG (multi-layer) to PNG you can use ImageMagick cli tools, you should consider your projector resolution too.